# Print line with 4 leading whitespaces - grep and awk handle ERE differently

Tags: regex, unix, awk, grep, posix

I am trying to print a line with 4 leading whitespaces.
When I apply my *regex* with *egrep*, everything works as *expected*.
But when I use *awk*, the results highly *differ*.

Can u say what I am doing wrong?

Example:

```
echo "    testtest" | egrep '^[[:space:]]{4}'
```

=> prints:    testtest

```
echo "    testtest" | awk '/^[[:space:]]{4}/ {print}'
```

=> prints nothing

Comment: `awk` command it working fine for me, what's your `awk` version?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Hi, my version is: mawk 1.3.4 20200120

Comment: This is valid awk code, but doesn't work in `mawk`. I believe it's a bug and should be reported. The best solution is to use a different awk implementation if available (try `gawk`), or install a different awk.

Comment: The POSIX character class `[[:space:]]` is not part of the base Awk feature set; I imagine this is already documented in the Mawk manual. Try `^[ \t]{4}` if you are just looking for a way to have it work reliably across Awk versions

Comment: @tripleee even if i use \s or \t, it doesn't work. ==>
  echo "(whitespace x 4)    testtest" | awk '/^[\t]{4}/ {print}'
  echo " (whitespace x 4)   testtest" | awk '/^[\s]{4}/ {print}'
---> prints nothing

Comment: I would not expect `\s` to work, it's a Perl extension. You seem to have mistyped `[ \t]` which contains a space and `\t` (for tab) inside a character class.

Comment: @tripleee but even  [ \t] (with space) doesn't work. ==> echo "(whitespace x 4) testtest" | awk '/^[ \t]{4}/ {print}' --> prints nothing

Comment: True, I managed to repro with `mawk` now (tested with Busybox before and it worked fine, so I conceded even Mawk should work too then!) If you only need literal spaces to work, simply `/^ {4}/` should be fine.

Comment: `mawk` seems to have a problem with tabs more generally; even including a literal tab character in the character class doesn't work.

Comment: @tripleee awk uses POSIX extended regular expressions with additional C escapes (`\t` etc) so I believe character classes are POSIX awk. The bug is reproducible for me with `echo x | mawk '/x{1}/'`, and other variations which print nothing (version `1.3.4`). I believe it's related to how mawk is parsing curly braces (and not related to character classes or whitespace).

Comment: Here is the bug: https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1815304.html

Comment: As mentioned in that report, it's not a bug, it's a feature (aka "known limitation") :-). That's simply not [yet] supported functionality as opposed to a bug which is functionality that is supposed to be supported but doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to avoid GNU Awk for whatever reason, see if `nawk` is available for your platform. Your version information looks similar but not identical to the `mawk` version in Debian, where you can use `update-alternatives` to prefer a different `awk` implementation system-wide. `nawk` is the Debian package name for what is otherwise still known as the original Aho, Kernighan, and Weinberger implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your comment that `echo "(whitespace x 4) testtest" | awk '/^[ \t]{4}/ {print}' --> prints nothing` as well as the issue in your question - with `mawk 1.3.4` you're running a pre-POSIX version of a minimal featured (for execution speed) variant of awk, `mawk 1`, so you shouldn't expect it to understand relatively modern POSIX concepts like character classes (`[[:space:]]`) or RE intervals (`{4}`) or non-POSIX extensions like `\s` or various other things. `mawk 2` is now available which should have better support of POSIX features but get GNU awk, `gawk`, for the fullest functionality and excellent speed.

By the way, `egrep` is deprecated, use `grep -E` instead.

Answer (score 1):

inaccuracies I need to point out :

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN { 
>     __="[[:space:]]"
>
>     for(_=_<_; (_+_) < 4^4; _++) { 
>          if(sprintf("%c",_)~__)  { 
>              printf("U + %6.4X\n",_) } } }'
> ```

```
U +   0009    # horizontal tab \t
U +   000A
U +   000B
U +   000C    # \f
U +   000D    
U +   0020    # space "[ ]"
```

1. `mawk-1` recognizes `POSIX` spaces properly in the `ASCII` side of things
2. `mawk-2`, at its current beta stage, doesn't yet solve the `{n,m}` interval problem that `mawk-1` faces

as for matching 4 spaces up front, something like

```
echo "    testtest"  |
```

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN { _="[ \t]"; gsub(".",_,_); _^=FS=("^")_ } _<NF'
>
>     or
>
> # if u wanna be posixly-pedantic about it
>
> mawk 'BEGIN { _^=FS="^"(_=(_="[[:space:]]")_)_ } _<NF'
> ```

```
    testtest
```